# Rename [presidency-term] to [presidential-term]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [presidency-term](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidency-term), but

1. It's poor English ([writers use presidential term](https://www.rt.com/politics/421701-putin-discloses-primary-objective/))
2. It isn't in line with other similar tags (i.e. [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has been done.  I've also created a synonym between the two.